# What suffix/reference is used for decibels in AnalyserNode?

Tags: web-audio-api

The [documentation](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-analysernode-interface) for the AnalyserNode doesn't specify what reference suffix is used for `analyser.maxDecibels` or `analyser.minDecibels` Does anyone happen to know what that suffix is?

Answer (score 0):

The [FFT Windowing](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#fft-windowing-and-smoothing-over-time) section (See Conversion to dB) tells how the AnalyserNode computes the dB values.

Not really sure what you mean by "reference suffix".

Comment: From my understanding of decibels, they need a suffix of some sort to quantify what you're measuring, such as dBSPL or dBFS.

Comment: Probably dBFS, then.